# React component not rendering with Link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a problem using react, redux and react router.

When I navigate through pages using < Link > the components don't completly re-render.

For instance : If I am on the login page and I go to the register page (using a Link), in the latter, some css/js elements won't appear correctly.

Here is my code : (without imports and irrelevant details)

### **Main component**

```
class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container-scroller">
        <LoadingBar showFastActions style={{ backgroundColor: 'orange', height: '4px' }}  />
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Router history={History}>
            <Switch>
              <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={DashboardPage} />
              <PrivateRoute exact path="/facility" component={FacilityPage} />
              <Route exact path="/register" component={RegisterPage} />
              <Route exact path="/signin" component={SignInPage} />
              <Route exact path="/signout" component={Signout} />
              <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
            </Switch>
          </Router>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

### **Login page :**

```
class SignInPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      email: '',
      password: ''
    };
  }

  handleChange = e => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    this.setState({ [name]: value });
  }

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.signIn(this.state.inputEmail, this.state.inputPassword);
  }

  render() {

    {/* redirect user if already logged in */}
    let token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    if (token) {
      return <Redirect to='/' />
    }

    return (
      // sign in form
      <div className="mt-3 text-center">
        <Link to="/register" className="auth-link text-white">
          Don't have an account ?
          <span class="font-weight-medium"> Sign in</span>
        </Link>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    errors: state.auth.errors,
  };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    signIn: (email, password) => {
      return dispatch(userActions.signIn(email, password));
    }
  };
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SignInPage));
```

### **Register page :**

```
import '../../node_modules/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js';
import '../assets/js/form-validation.js';

class RegisterPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      email: '',
      password: '',
      password_confirmation: '',
      first_name: '',
      last_name: '',
    };
  }

  handleChange = e => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    this.setState({ [name]: value });
  }

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {

    {/* redirect user if already logged in */}
    let token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    if (token) {
      return <Redirect to='/' />
    }

    return (
      // register form
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    errors: state.users.errors,
  };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    signIn: (email, password, firstName, lastName) => {
      return dispatch(userActions.register(email, password, firstName, lastName));
    }
  };
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(RegisterPage));
```

It seems that I am not the only one to have this problem. I have tried the withRouter solution and it does not work.

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: where is your css being imported from

Comment: In an index.js file that create the redux store and render the App component.
The css works in the register page, but some elements such as checkbox don't appear on the page and buttons don't work.
And the 2 JS files that I import in my RegisterPage seem not to be imported.

Comment: I think you should check that you're importing those needed files correct. check that the modules are properly exported from those files too. and if you have styles that are specific to components, i think it works better to import directly into those component than the broad importing into index.js

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the render? Can you create a working fiddle (representative of the error)?
I think the component returned by withRouter is not doing exactly what you expect it does.